# How can I populate my FK column in one table with the FK from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got a football world cup database. These are the two important table I'm working on right now:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries(
   Cid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Clubs(
   Ncid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   Cid INT REFERENCES Countries NOT NULL
);
```

So I added a column 'country' in the clubs table which represents the country the club is in. The problem now is I need to populate the `cid` column of the clubs table with the `cid` that matches the country in the countries table.

I have tried this and it didn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE clubs ADD COLUMN country VARCHAR(255)
INSERT INTO clubs(name, country) 
SELECT DISTINCT club_name, club_country 
FROM tempsquads; //this loads the data from a temporary tabe into my table

INSERT INTO clubs(cid) 
SELECT cid 
FROM countries 
WHERE clubs.country = countries.name;
```

Has anyone an idea of how I can perform such a query?

Comment: I'm missing something.  How do you know what country a club is in?

Comment: i get that information from a csv file that has all of the world cup data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your INSERT, link tempsquads to country:

```
INSERT INTO CLUBS(name, cid)
(SELECT t.club_name, c.cid
FROM tempsquads t
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES c ON t.club_country=c.name)
```

Don't add the country name field to the clubs table--you will link on id when you need the name.

Comment: thank you so much it worked! I didnt know that i can use inner joins for that.